# Как сделать, чтобы текст в TextView не переносился на новую строку

Tags: java, android, android-studio, textview

Есть простой TextView в активити с Шириной match_parent и высотой wrap_content.
так вот если текст в нем не вмещаеться в одну линию то оно переходит на новую. Так вот можно ли как то сделать чтобы обрезалось. Т.е. что вместеться в одну линию будет видно остольное обрежаться

Comment: Увеличиваете ширину, и делаете выровнение по центру.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Добавьте в xml атрибут `android:maxLines="1"`. Все слова, которые не влезут, он будет обрезать.

Если вам надо в конце ставить `...`, показывая, что еще есть слова, используйте `android:ellipsize="end"`